# HDP sanbox: yum install is throwing 403 error

Tags: hadoop, hortonworks-data-platform, hdp, hortonworks-sandbox

I am trying to setup HDP sandbox and work on a big data project.But when trying to do yum install, I am getting below error

```html
http://s3.amazonaws.com/dev.hortonworks.com/ambari/centos6/2.x/BUILDS/2.4.0.0-1225/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] PYCURL ERROR 22 - "The requested URL returned error: 403 Forbidden"
Trying other mirror.
To address this issue please refer to the below knowledge base article

https://access.redhat.com/solutions/69319

If above article doesn't help to resolve this issue please open a ticket with Red Hat Support.

Error: Cannot retrieve repository metadata (repomd.xml) for repository: AMBARI.2.4.0.0-2.x. Please verify its path and try again
```

I tried below instructions:
in /etc/yum.repos.d/sandbox.repo, updated the enabled=0

yum clean all

yum update

But yum update gives me this error.I cannot even install any python related libraries to proceed with my work.Can someone give me solution for this error.
Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, and in order to solve it, I backed up the repositories:

- ambari.repo
- HDP.repo
- HDP-UTILS.repo

then I removed them from the /yum.repos.d folder.

Then I ran the following command:

```
yum clean all
```

After that the yum update worked, and I managed to install the things I needed.

** What I noticed, is that whenever I tried to use any YUM command, it gave preference to these repositories that I mentioned.